# Seeking explanation for an identity in: "Polynomials such that roots=coefficients"

Tags: calculus, polynomials

In the following thread here: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/66096/legranddodom, LeGrandDODOM stated the following identity (2): $ \sum\limits_{1 \le i < j \le n} z_i z_j = z_2 $

for: $(z_1,\ldots, z_n) \in \left(\mathbb R-\{0\}\right)^n$ and:

$ (X-z_1)...(X-z_n)=X^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z_kX^{n-k}$

How is identity $(2)$ derived? The other two identities: $(1)$ and $(3)$ are pretty straightforward I guess, though in $(1)$ is probably a typo: $ \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} z_k = -z_1 $ 
,the start of the index of the sum should be $k = 0 $ and $-z_1$ could be replaced by an abitrary $z_j , 0\le j \le n $;

Comment: Those are the Vieta's rules https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you look at the problem in a combinatorial way. How can you obtain a term of degree $n-2$? You need to choose two roots and then only $X$.